# Webpack :: How to Bundle 3rd party angular modules

Tags: angularjs, webpack, build

Im quite new to webpack, this is my scenario

I have an Angular 1.5 application working with webpack, it didn't used to include the vendor libraries since the application loaded them from a CDN.

This is changing so I needed to also bundle the 3rd party libraries, looking around I added this to my webpack.config.js:

```
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        minChunks: ({ resource }) => /node_modules/.test(resource),
        filename: 'vendor.bundle.js'
    }),
```

This worked prety cool, including only what was imported by the app instead of pulling whole libraries.

My problem is how to include, in the vendor file, the 3rd party modules that my angular application is using, for example, having this:

```
    import * as ng from "angular";
    import { IStateProvider, IUrlRouterProvider, IState } from "angular-ui-router";

    ng.module('fmacapp', ["ui.grid", "ngDialog"]).config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", (stateprovider: IStateProvider, urlRouterProvider: IUrlRouterProvider) => {
        //State config here
    }
```

How can I include the ui.grid and ngDialog in the vendor file, since they are not being imported into the app, is there a way to do this dynamically?